# MVC 5 - Ninject - Tasks Thread Running Oddly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a thread that shoots events to run programs at certain times.

I do want the website to have full control over the process so that is why I built it into the site as a long term thread that loops.

The issue is I scheduled a task to happen at a particular time and it happens almost randomly (maybe when I load the page). It seems as if the web app sleeps all threads until its used or something.

Here is the code:

```
public void run()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var lastDate = InternalEventLogger.GetLastDateTime();
                if (DateTime.Now >= lastDate.AddDays(1))
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(lastDate.AddDays(1));
                    InternalEventLogger.RefreshLog();
                }
                bool needUpdate = false;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("this");
                List<Event> tempList = new List<Event>(this.evtList.getList());
                foreach (Event evt in this.evtList.getList())
                {
                    if (!evt.status.Equals("success"))
                        continue;
                    if (evt.nextRun <= DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        var tempEvt = evt;
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("time to run: "+evt.name);
                        tempList.Remove(evt);
                        tempEvt.nextRun = evt.nextRun.AddMinutes(evt.interval);
                        tempEvt.lastRan = DateTime.Now;
                        tempList.Add(tempEvt);
                        needUpdate = true;
                        if (tempEvt.runLocation != null) 
                        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            Process p = new Process();
                            p.StartInfo.FileName = tempEvt.runLocation;
                            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                            p.Start();
                            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                            string err = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                            InternalEventLogger.WriteLog(output);
                            InternalEventLogger.WriteLog("// ------------- ERROR -------------- \n" + err);
                            p.WaitForExit();
                        });
                    }
                }
                if (needUpdate)
                {
                    this.evtList.setList(tempList);
                    this.evtList.serialize(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlEventLocation"]);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Default);
    }
```

Ran from:

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        evtManager = new EventManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlEventLocation"]);
        evtManager.run();
        // Initalize Event Logger
        new InternalEventLogger();
    }
```

Here is a pic that shows the problem in timing:
[image]

**UPDATE**

Tried the settings below and still not working properly!

Only at visit does it start the tasks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recycling timer on IIS Settings needed to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem in your IIS web server settings. IIS Application Pool have parameter (in advanced settings): Idle Time-out (minutes). By default this settings is 20 minutes. So when there are no queries to web site during 20 minutes web server stops Application Pool process.

[Idle Time-out](http://aspnetfaq.com/iis7-application-pool-idle-time-out-settings/) parameter explanation.
Link to [Microsoft Technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956(WS.10).aspx)

Comment: Ok. Problem not in Application Pool Idle Time-out. Another suggestion: may be there are some exception arise in Task code. Use try-catch and log exception to solve problem.

Comment: That's not it since, it runs fine after I visit the site

Comment: Do you catch exception inside Task.Factory.StartNew ? I mean `Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>{ try { ... } catch(Exception ex) { [log it here] } })`